# T-Sql How to return a table from a storedproc in another stored proc

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

I would like to do the following.  Basically have a stored procedure call another stored procedure that returns a table.    How is this done?

```
    ALTER PROC [GETSomeStuff]
    AS
    BEGIN
    
    @table = EXEC CB_GetLedgerView @accountId, @fromDate, @toDate, @pageSize, @pageNumber, @filter, @status, @sortExpression, @sortOrder, @virtualCount OUTPUT

    SELECT * FROM @table
    --Do some other stuff here        
    END
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The target of a stored procedure has to be a temp or actual table so you can

```
    Insert into #table exec CB_GetLedgerView @accountId, @fromDate, 
@toDate, @pageSize, @pageNumber, 
@filter, @status, @sortExpression, 
@sortOrder, @virtualCount OUTPUT
```

If the output result set of the stored procedure does not match the ordinal positions and count of the rows in the target table, specify a column list.

Comment: The exception to this is that if you have an insert into a temporary table within the sproc, then you cannot then insert its output into another temp table

Answer (score 5):

The temporary-table approach, at least as expressed above, didn't work for me. You can use a variable, just as easily.

```
DECLARE @return_value INT
DECLARE @tblOutputTable TABLE(Col1 BIT NOT NULL, Col2 INT NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO @tblOutputTable EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[SomeSp] @Param1 = 15, @Param2 = 2
```