# Insert Output of a stored procedure to a temp table

Tags: t-sql

when trying to write the output of a stored procedure into a temp table, I get the error message

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Line 4
>   Invalid object name '#tblTemp '.

My query is this:

```
DECLARE @group_name varchar(250)
SET @group_name = 'somevalue'

INSERT INTO #tblTemp EXEC mySchema.sp_MyStoredProc @group_name OUTPUT

SELECT  *
FROM    #tblTemp 

DROP TABLE #tblTemp
```

What is wrong here?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: FYI, tried to use [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504431/t-sql-how-to-return-a-table-from-a-storedproc-in-another-stored-proc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use temp table this way in `INSERT INTO` you should define this table first.

```
CREATE TABLE #tblTemp(
ID int,
....
)
```

In T-SQL a temp table can be created automatically using following command:

```
select * into #tblTemp
from table
```

You can use this syntax in your case with stored procedure results using `OPENROWSET`.

[Here is the answer on SO which can help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/how-to-select-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 3):

You need to create the #temp table with e.g. a `CREATE TABLE` statement before you can `INSERT INTO` it.